# Rigid bar suspended by two ropes, tension of first rope after second rope is cut?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

This is from a practice exam, I've been sitting here thinking about it for over an hour and can't convince myself of an answer, or write down any relevant exact equations.

A bar of uniform density $\rho$, length $L$, and negligible width is suspended by two inextensible ropes of negligible mass.

The second rope is cut, what is the tension of the other rope shortly after cutting? 
What is the tension's rate of change?

I've been trying to work it out with numbers $g=10 m/s^2$, $\rho=30kg/m$ and $L=1m$ just to keep it simple. Obviously before the rope is cut the tension of both ropes is $T_1 = T_2 = 150N$ and after the bar falls down and is stationary, then $T_1 = 300N$ so there is some smooth function of the tension (I think). The angle between the first rope and the bar is $90\deg$ and increases to $180\deg$, and the force due to gravity can be divided into normal and tangential forces. The normal force increases the angular momentum, and the normal force is a maximum the moment the rope is cut. I'm having trouble putting this all together, but I think I am on the right track. Thanks in advance.

edit: As stated below, this is the force of gravity components $F_N = \rho Lg Sin(\theta )$ and $F_T = -\rho Lg Cos(\theta )$

I still have trouble applying angular momenta to this problem.

Comment: Did you do a free body diagram, which includes inertial forces?

Comment: @ja72 yes, but that doesn't illustrate the angular momentum of the bar very well. Using symmetries (note that $\theta$ goes from $90\deg$ to $180\deg$) I calculated $F_N = \rho Lg Sin(\theta )$ and $F_T = -\rho Lg Cos(\theta )$

Comment: The problem has two degrees of freedom. One is the rod orientation and the other is the rope angle. Solving for both is doable, but rather complex. Getting the results immediately after the cut is a much simpler problem because the rod is horizontal and the rope vertical, and nothing has velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assume horizontal Rod*

Sum of forces equals acceleration of center of gravity

$$ T - m g = m \ddot{y}_C $$

Sum of moments about center of gravity equals mass moment of inertia times angular acceleration

$$ T \frac{L}{2} = I \ddot{\theta} $$

As the bar rotates by a small angle $\theta$ the center of gravity height is found by $y = -\frac{L}{2} \theta$ or by differentiating twice, $\ddot{y} = -\frac{L}{2} \ddot{\theta}$

Together it all comes as

$$ \begin{aligned} T & = m g - m \frac{L}{2} \ddot\theta 
\\ T \frac{L}{2} & = \left( \frac{m}{12} L^2 \right) \ddot \theta \end{aligned} $$

Solve the above for $T$ and $\ddot{\theta}$.  Hint the value does not *have* to be more than $\frac{m g}{2}$.

Comment: How do you get $T\frac{L}{2}$? I don't follow that, but I understand the rest completely.

Comment: Solving for T I got mg/4 as an answer, which doesn't seem to make sense, why would the tension be cut in half?

Comment: Personally I would do the moments calculation about the point of suspension by the second rope. That way you wouldn't have to worry about any issues arising from the fact that your centre of mass is not in an inertial frame (it is accelerating).

Comment: Are you assuming that the rope doesn't oscillate?

Comment: $T \frac{L}{2}$ is force times distance, for the total moment applied on the center of the rod.

Comment: Yep $T=\frac{m g}{4}$ is the correct answer. Part of the the static load went to keep the rod horizontal, which is not needed anymore and the load actually decreases.

Comment: @G.Paily you cannot take moments about any point you want when you do dynamics. Only in statics. When motion is considered the moment about the CG is what is used.

Comment: I was mistaken, there is no problem with non-inertial frames here. @ja72 , the same calculation carries through even when evaluated about the point of suspension: $$mg - T =ma$$ and $$mg\frac{L}{2} = m\frac{L^2}{3}\alpha = \frac{2mLa}{3}$$ which gives the same answer of $$T=\frac{mg}{4}$$

Comment: @G.Paily provided you use the correct mass moment of inertia. $I=\frac{m}{12} L^2$ if taken about the CG, and $I=\frac{1}{3}L^2$ if taken from the end.

Comment: Well, yes, I thought that went without saying :-) . The moment of inertia is a property of a body AND the pivot point, since you are trying to describe the resistance to angular acceleration about the pivot.

Comment: @G.Paily in your second equation, what does the last term represent? How do you reach that calculation? Because $\frac{L}{2}\alpha = a$? And that $mg\frac{L}{2}$ is the only torque applied? I was thinking that the rope itself provided a torque, why is that line of reasoning incorrect?

Comment: @ja72 that's fascinating, this problem has really played around with my intuition. thanks for your solution, it was a big help.

Comment: @walczyk yes, $\frac{L}{2}\alpha = a$. Since in my calculation I am evaluating the torques about the point of suspension, NOT the centre of mass, any forces acting _through_ the point of suspension contribute zero torque about the point of suspension. In that case the only torque is due to the weight. And, as mentioned above, one must be careful to use the right moment of inertia.

Comment: @G.Paily I know this was awhile ago, but I came back to this problem to recheck the solution. Your solution makes a lot more intuitive sense, since the force of gravity on the CM is causing the torque, in the other frame we say the tension is applying the torque, which is less clear. You both talked about difficulties of accelerating CoM, but solved it in two different frames. What should I read that talks about the subtleties of this choice? Thanks again for your solution, it's helped me twice now)